# Chart using highcharts and Json asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, highcharts

This is the first time i try to use Json 
i can't solve this problem
the controller

return this json

```
[
{"ID":1,"month":"september","sale":120},
{"ID":2,"month":"september","sale":122}
]
```

the chart needs data in this format

```
 data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                 }]
```

how to get the data returned by the controller to the chart in the right format??

This solution don't work

```
var data=[];
        var uri = 'api/chartapi';

/*   $(function () {

         $.getJSON(uri)
             .done(function (json) {

                 $.each(data, function (name, score) { {
                     data.push({
                          name: name,

                        y: score

                     });


                 }

                 });
             });
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply parse that format on js? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/992/

```
var data = [],
    json = [{
        "ID": 1,
            "month": "september",
            "sale": 120
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
            "month": "september",
            "sale": 122
    }];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    data.push({
        name: json[i].month,
        id: json[i].ID,
        y: json[i].sale
    });
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Comment: can i make the controller send json in this format instead [
{"month":"september","sale":120},
{"month":"september","sale":122}
]

Comment: I don't know your controller, sorry.